# How can I connect Memcached to multiple VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, connection, azure

I'm very new to the concept of VMs. I have 2 VMs with memcached installed in both having same port number. I want to link these two VMs so that if one fails, I still have the other one functioning with running memcached service. Can anyone please explain how I can do that asap.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a load balancer. As I understand you want an exact copy of your application in both servers. Then you should use a third one to serve the traffic from the other two. You can use nginx or squid or something similar to do the balancing...